# error when query table for multiple conditions

Tags: python, numpy

What am I doing wrong here?

```
nondrinkers_21 = bootstrap3[bootstrap3['drinks_coffee']==False]['age']=='<21'['height'].mean()
```

TypeError: string indices must be integers

I'm trying to find the mean height of coffee drinkers under 21 from a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your brackets are in the wrong place.

```
nondrinkers_21 = (bootstrap3[(bootstrap3['drinks_coffee']==False) & (bootstrap3['age']<21)])['height'].mean()
```